# What is this triangle inside an octagon symbol and square bracket notation?

Tags: functions

I defined a function in Mathematica online and I get this strange output. What does the triangle inside the octagon mean? Also, what is `[n]`? Also, why is there a `y` in the output when I haven't defined it?

```
f[k_,n_]=Sum[k!/(n!(n-k)!),{k,0,n}]
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is a [DifferenceRoot](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DifferenceRoot.html).

Comment: Did you mean to write $k!/(n!(n-k)!)$?  Or did you mean $n!/(k!(n-k)!)$?  There's a well-known identity involving the summation of the latter option, but I don't think there's one for the first.

Comment: When you see a new symbol that you don't know, try putting `\\FullForm` at the end of the line and running it again

Comment: That's an octagon, not a hexagon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, I guess it is a shorthand for this elaborate function which I got by evaluating your expression in *Mathematica* on my desktop.

```
(1/n!)DifferenceRoot[
  Function[{\[FormalY], \[FormalN]}, {-\[FormalY][\[FormalN]] + (5 + 
         2 \[FormalN]) \[FormalY][
        1 + \[FormalN]] + (-10 - 
         6 \[FormalN] - \[FormalN]^2) \[FormalY][
        2 + \[FormalN]] + (3 + \[FormalN]) \[FormalY][
        3 + \[FormalN]] == 0, \[FormalY][1] == 2, \[FormalY][2] == 7/
     2, \[FormalY][3] == 26/3}]][n]
```

Answer (score 3):

As noted in the comments, this is a `DifferenceRoot` object.  If you click on the oblong, you get a few more details:

[image]

What this means is that the denominator $y(n)$ satisfies the relationships $$
(n+3) y(n+3) - (n^2 + 6n + 10) y(n+2) + (2n+5) y(n+1) - y(n) = 0 \\
y(1) = 2 \qquad y(2) = \frac{7}{2} \qquad y(3) = \frac{26}{3}.
$$
These relations are sufficient to determine all of the coefficients.  Usually this also means that Mathematica can't simplify the result any more than this.

Comment: Any ideas as to why it's represented as a circle with a triangle in the middle?

Comment: @Joe:  My best guess is that the triangle is supposed to be a delta (∆), which is a symbol for differences.  People who work on ordinary difference equations or partial difference equations often abbreviate them as "O∆E"s and "P∆E"s to distinguish them from differential equations.

Comment: Oh I see that's interesting thank you. I've not seen them called O$\Delta$E before.